# Solving a function that carries a numerical approximation as variable

Tags: equation-solving

I want to find the zero of a function that is a function of a numerical approximation. The simplest example that mimics my real problem I could find is:

```
fx[y_, z_] := 
 FindRoot[0.25*x + Log[x] - Log[y] + 0.5*z, {x, 5}][[1, 2]]
g[y_, z_] := 0.1*fx[y, z] + 0.1*z
h[y_, z_] := 0.5*fx[y, z] - 2*z
condition[y_, z_] := 0.3 - g[y, z] + 0.6*h[y, z]
```

We can clearly see that, for a given z, there is y such that condition[y,z]=0 holds:

```
tabletest = Table[{yy, condition[yy, 1]}, {yy, 27, 31, 0.1}];
ListLinePlot[{tabletest}, 
 AxesLabel -> {"y", 
   Row[{"Condition"}, BaseStyle -> {FontFamily -> "Libertine"}]}]
```

[image]
However, when I try to solve for condition[y,z]==0 I get an error:

```
Solve[condition[yy, 1] == 0 && 28 <= yy <= 29, yy]
```

> "The function value {-1.77759-1.\ Log[yy]} is not a list of numbers \
>   with dimensions {1} at {x} = {0.1}. "

I am clearly doing something wrong but I can't tell what. Anyone can help me?

Comment: The function fx[y, z] evaluates to Log[x]. Since there is no numerical value assigned to x, this is "not a list of numbers". What do you expect fx[y,z] to be?

Comment: fx[y,z] gives me the value x such that fx[y,z]==0. For example. fx[29, 1]=5.01748. But if I want to find the root of fx[y,1] such that y obeys condition[yy, 1] == 0 I can't, for some reason.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Functions that directly or indirectly use numeric techniques should be restricted to numeric arguments with [`NumericQ`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/NumericQ.html)

```
fx[y_?NumericQ, z_?NumericQ] :=
  FindRoot[1/4*x + Log[x] - Log[y] + 1/2*z, {x, 5}][[1, 2]];
g[y_?NumericQ, z_?NumericQ] := (fx[y, z] + z)/10;
h[y_?NumericQ, z_?NumericQ] := 1/2*fx[y, z] - 2*z;
condition[y_?NumericQ, z_?NumericQ] := 3/10 - g[y, z] + 3/5*h[y, z];
```

Since you know that `28 <= yy <= 29` use `FindRoot` rather than `Solve`

```
soln = FindRoot[condition[yy, 1] == 0, {yy, 28.5}]

(* {yy -> 28.773} *)

Plot[condition[yy, 1], {yy, 27, 31}, Epilog -> {Red,
   AbsolutePointSize[6], Point[{yy, condition[yy, 1]} /. soln]}]
```

[image]

Comment: Of course. That is great. Thank you very much, Bob Harlon! :)